# How do I iterate over elements of a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a small client/server program for encrypted network communications and have the following struct to allow the endpoints to negotiate capabilities.

```
struct KeyExchangePacket {
    kexinit: u8,
    replay_cookie: [u8; 32],
    kex_algorithms: String,
    kgen_algorithms: String,
    encryption_algorithms: String,
    mac_algorithms: String,
    compression_algorithms: String,
    supported_languages: String,
}
```

I need to convert the fields into bytes in order to send them over a `TcpStream`, but I currently have to convert them one at a time.

```
send_buffer.extend_from_slice(kex_algorithms.as_bytes());
send_buffer.extend_from_slice(kgen_algorithms.as_bytes());
etc...
```

Is there a way to iterate over the fields and push their byte values into a buffer for sending?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is there a way to iterate over the fields

No. You have to implement it yourself, or find a macro / compiler plugin that will do it for you.

See [How to iterate or map over tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29148544/155423) for a similar question.

Think about how iterators work. An iterator has to yield a **single** type for each iteration. What would that type be for your struct composed of at least 3 different types?

Comment: Pretty sure serde could be useful here if a compiler plugin/nightly is acceptable.

Comment: @mcarton are you aware of a serde adaptor for generic bytes? Or do you think OP would have to write such an adaptor?

Comment: what do you mean? serde itself can serialize from/to `Vec<u8>`.

Comment: @mcarton interesting! I assumed that serde could output a struct using something like JSON or XML or MessagePack to a `Vec<u8>`, but didn't know that there was a mode to smush all the bytes of a struct together. How would I tell serde to output OP's data without any serialization format?

Answer (score 3):

[Bincode](https://github.com/TyOverby/bincode) does this.

```
let packet = KeyExchangePacket { /* ... */ };
let size_limit = bincode::SizeLimit::Infinite;
let encoded: Vec<u8> = bincode::serde::serialize(&packet, size_limit).unwrap();
```

From the readme:

> The encoding (and thus decoding) proceeds unsurprisingly -- primitive types are encoded according to the underlying Writer, tuples and structs are encoded by encoding their fields one-by-one, and enums are encoded by first writing out the tag representing the variant and then the contents.